# Запись в консоль происходит после завершение программы

Tags: c++, linux, c

Коллеги, приветствую.

У меня есть программа, которая с помощью семафоров синхронизирует 3 потока. Но есть проблема, которая представлена на картинке

[image: Консоль]

Такое чувство, будто после завершения программы потоки еще не выполнились до конца и продолжают выполнятся.

Листинг кода на гисте: https://gist.github.com/ArtemTellur/d7af7dfc4c4dcf08bb396b98345a248a

Разъясните пожалуйста, нормальное ли это поведение. Если нет, то в чем может быть ошибка?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Кэширование вывода в `printf`?

Comment: @Arhad что это значит?

Comment: 1. [mcve] (вся необходимая информация должна быть приведена прямо в тексте вопроса) 2. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вызывайте `fflush()` после каждого printf для сброса буферизированного вывода

Comment: @Mike поставил после каждого printf'а fflush(stdout); - не помогло.

Comment: Потоки надо join'ить перед выходом. `man waitpid`.